# Difference between --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0, or loopback, or actual IP

Tags: monerod, security, full-node, daemon, rpc

I run a node from home.  I use `--rpc-bind-ip` as a daemon flag, with my internal/LAN IP address as the argument.  With this setup, I can access my node from wallets on different computers inside my LAN.  When others ask this question, I've seen advice to bind to `0.0.0.0`, and I've seen advice to bind to loopback (`127.0.0.1`) (mainly when you'll connect somehow through hidden services, apparently).

How does `monerod` behave differently with different bindings?  Would the recommendation for which one to use change if the Monero node were be run on remote VPS rather than as a home node?  Would the recommendation change if running a home node that is meant to be accessed from outside the LAN?

*If loopback is strictly for hidden services, then that's probably outside the scope of this question, since I'm mainly curious about binding to `0.0.0.0` versus actual, internal or external IP.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic networking question, not specific to Monero.

`0.0.0.0` means "any address" - it will bind to every network interface on the machine. So it will listen to requests from anywhere.

Using a specific address means it will only bind to that single address.

Using `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, so it will only listen to requests originating on the same machine.